Help with choosing stats test for bird count data
I am a university student working on analyzing some data, and am looking for a little bit of statistics help and guidance.
Data overview:
I am doing a research project on birds, and am trying to understand how the use of an audio lure impacts observations of 5 species. We did 400 point counts - each was a 5 minute period where we counted all individuals of our target species in a certain area. For 200 of them we used the audio lure, and for 200 of them we did not.
I now want to do some simple tests to check if the use of the audio lure had a significant impact on observations for each of the five species.
I first thought about doing a paired T-test, but then I tried, maybe incorrectly, to check for normal distribution, and from my understanding the data was not normally distributed, so it would be better to use a glm. I then reasoned that using a glm with Poisson distribution would make the most sense, because Poisson deals with count data, and not presence/absence like Binomial distribution.
Unfortunately, this is about where my reasoning stops. I think I have a general grasp of the ideas and theories behind each of the tests, but I am just not confident enough in any of my decisions to feel comfortable saying “this is for sure the right approach.” I have tried watching a few videos, but for whatever reason I just cannot grasp some of the concepts well enough to apply them to my specific data set, and ultimately I have ended up more confused.
If someone would be willing to help walk me through the process of deciding which test makes most sense for my data, that would be really awesome.
I am attaching histograms of my data, just to give an idea of what I am working with.
Please let me know if you have any questions or if I need to provide anything else.



My first reaction would be that this is a count outcome, not continuous, so things like count distributions seem like a good idea.
In practice, very few counts will follow a Poisson distribution, because locations (or patients, or shops etc.) vary in characteristics we haven't even measured. I.e. there's some underlying characteristic (kind of a not-directly observed latent characteristic of the location that says how high counts tend to be in the location compared to other locations with the same covariates).
One way to capture is to say the the (log-)Poisson rate varies between locations. If you say that the Poisson rate varies according to a Gamma distribution, you end up with a negative binomial distribution, if you integrate out the Gamma-random effect. You can then account for covariates using Negative-Binomial regression. The awkward thing is that when you have two paired locations, that's hard to capture, because you just integrated out the random effect to get the distribution for one location at a time. An alternative is to assume that the log-Poisson rate varies according to a normal distribution (or equivalently, the Poisson rate varies according to a log-normal distribution), this leads to random effects Poisson regression. So, to use R notation from the lme4 package, something like
glmer( count ~ 1 + (1|location) + audio_lure + further covariates + 
               offset(log_time), family=poisson(link="log"))

, where a log-observation time offset mostly matters if you have different durations of observation at different sites and you assume that the count is proportional to the time you observed the location for.
To be honest, when you look at a particular Gamma distribution, you can find a lognormal distribution that looks pretty similar, so it's usually not particularly obvious why to choose one over the other other than convenience.
One thing that might be the case though is that counts within location are overdispersed for the location (i.e. even if you did lots of measurements on the same location under the same conditions and estimate the location specific Poisson rate, it looks like the occasions have a overdispersed distribution vs. the Poisson). In that case a negative binomial distribution with a normally distributed random effect on the log-negative-binomial rate would be an option that is available in standard software.
Another option is if you say you don't want to assume a distribution, in which case you could say that you have one fixed parameter describing every location. So, to use R notation, again, something like
glm(count ~ 0 + location + audio_lure + further covariates + 
            offset(log_time), family=poisson(link="log"))

(where location is a factor variable - make sure it is and that you get an estimate per location) or the negative-binomial version thereof. This makes no assumptions about how the locations are different and tries to estimate how locations differ solely from the data of each location on its own without borrowing information from other locations (i.e. not assuming that rates vary per a gamma or log-normal distribution), but is also less efficient. The random effects version that makes a distributional assumption would exploit it, if from the data it appears that locations don't vary that much beyond what's explained by the covariates.

There are at least two issues here. One is that you have repeated measures (because you used the same places twice). The other is whether you want to include any covariates (such as the elevation, temperature, etc. of the areas.
If you want to include covariates (and have that data) then you will need some kind of regression model. You are on the right track with Poisson (since it is a count model) but, quite likely, you will need negative binomial regression, since Poisson regression assumes that the conditional variance is equal to the conditional mean, and that is rarely the case. But you  would need to account for the repeated measures which would, I think, require a nonlinear multilevel model. Those are complex.
So, let's ignore those (but be sure to note that you are ignoring them).
To compare two counts, you could try a paired t test for each species. That doesn't assume that the data are normally distributed, it assumes that the differences are. If that assumption is not met, you could try a Wilcoxon signed rank test.
There is also a spatial aspect to the data, but I think you can ignore that, for now.
As side notes:

Relying on YouTubes for learning stats is dangerous. There are some good ones, but also some poor ones. Anyone can make a YouTube. You should rely on a) Courses given by reputable places (universities or otherwise) and b) Good text books.

Your design is rather complex. It would have been good to ask about design before starting. One of my favorite quotes is from a Medieval king, Alfonso el Sabio of Castile.  He said



Had I been present at the creation, I would have recommended something
simpler.

